# Redirect in play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using play 2 with java and I want to do something like this: 
return ok("message") ;  and after the user see the message (after 2 sec ) he will be redireted to  "/home"

Comment: This question is not about Playframework specific, this question is about Javascript. See @biesior answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with HTML or JavaScript, there is nothing to do for Play framework with it.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://example.com/">
```

or

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
         window.location.href = 'http://example.com/'
    },2000);
</script>
```